# Passing an 'auto' declared std::shared_ptr<Derived> to std::shared_ptr<Base>&

Tags: c++, c++11

Compiling with `g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -g`

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr<Base>& ptr) {
    std::cout << "foo()\n";
    std::cout << "count = " << ptr.use_count() << "\n";     
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    auto d = std::make_shared<Derived>(5);
    foo(d);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
shared_ptr.cpp:47:10: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::shared_ptr<Base>&’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::shared_ptr<Base>’
     foo(d);
```

If I change the declaration of `d` to `std::shared_ptr<Base> d`
the code compiles.

My question is: do all type declarations with `auto` generate an r-value ?

Any reading material about this matter is much appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with lvalues or rvalues. Using plain pointers, instead of `std::shared_ptr`, will result in the same error (although `std::shared_ptr` also adds an extra ingredient to the situation). C++ simply doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do all type declarations with `auto` generate an r-value ?

No. And it's irrelevant here.

`d` is a `std::shared_ptr<Derive>`, but `foo` acceptes `std::shared_ptr<Base>`, then it needs to be converted to `std::shared_ptr<Base>`, which is a temporary object (an rvalue) and can't be bound to lvalue-reference to non-const, i.e. `std::shared_ptr<Base>&`.